# How to solve CentOS 7.5 LiveUSB kernel panic at boot on new PC (Gigabyte Z390 w/ Intel Core i9-9900K)

Tags: centos, kernel-panic

When booting a new PC (Gigabyte Z390 AORUS-Ultra w/ an Intel Core i9-9900K) I experience kernel panic at boot from a CentOS 7.5 LiveUSB which works OK on other PCs. BIOS is set to Factory Defaults, with the exception of setting Windows Features to Non-Windows. This appears on the display and may be relevant:

> Kernel panic - not syncing: Fatal exception
>   Kernel Offset: 0x4800000 from 0xffffffff81000000 (relocation range:
>   0xffffffff80000000-oxffffffffbfffffff)

A Fedora 29 workstation LiveUSB stalls after starting GNOME.

This PC survived multiple Burn-In Tests in Windows 10 with no problems, as well as by Memtest. It will also boot into Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS successfully.

Comment: Does the USB stick boot fine on another machine?

Comment: Yes, it does boot other PCs.

Comment: Have you tried CentOS 7.6 (1810)?